# SSH to last current location

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, bash

Is there a way to make the default ssh location be the folder that was current when last logged out?

I'm using bash and Ubuntu, so it looks like I could use the .bash_logout file to set a variable, but was wondering whether there is a better(/more correct) way.

Comment: With 'location' you mean your cwd (current working directory) and with  'folder' you mean directory?

Answer (score 1):

Use Gnu Screen is maybe the solution. Your shell stay open in screen (with your history, your path, your variables). Just connect to your server by SSH and do the `screen -r` to restore the session.

Comment: And you can happily put `screen -r` (or `-R` or `-x`) in your `.profile` so you don't even have to type it when you log in.

Comment: Makes logging out a bit tricky, though.